# How to set OR condition in Phalcon PHP ORM?

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

I using `Phalcon PHP` as PHP MVC Framework with `MongoDB`.
I can find object according with some criteria:

```
$user = User::findFirst(array(array('username' => $login, 'email'=> $login)));
```

As you can note, this request will return me the record according logical `AND` operator between conditions. I need to form request that will return result according with `OR` operator between conditions.

The problem also is that I'm using MongoDB, so, as I can suppose, I can't write `PHQL` request manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a matter of mangling PHP arrays

```
$user = User::findFirst( array( 
    '$or' => array(
        array( 'username' => $login),
        array( 'email' => $login)
    )
 ));
```

So not only do I show the answer but also how my totals non PHP mind solves this problem:

```
$result = '{ "$or": [ { "username": "login" }, { "email": "login" } ] }';
echo var_dump( json_decode( $result ) );

$test = array( 
    '$or' => array(
         array( 'username' => 'login'), array( 'email' => 'login')
     )
);

echo json_encode( $test ) ."\n"
```

So in just a few lines we converted and proved. So since you knew the JSON from either the manual page or reading another question on SO, just convert it. And it's one of the reasons I submit the valid JSON in responses here, is so that the logic can be translated into just about any language implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass column names as string in first param:

```
$user = User::findFirst('username = "'.$login.'" OR email = "'.$login.'"');
```

Comment: Not what the question was asking

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = '{ "$or": [ { "username": "login" }, { "email": "login" } ] }';
User::findFirst(array(json_decode($query,true)));
```

$result is the exact json which can be used to trigger queries in mongodb command line

json_decode with 2nd parameter true will output the array style format of JSON